# Syntax error when trying to import json to mongodb cloud collection

Tags: json, mongodb, cmd, import, mongodb-atlas

I created a database and collection in the MongoDB Atlas platform.
I wish to upload a simple .json to this collection.

From what I read on the documentation and online (including posts on SO), I am doing this:

1. run CMD from the folder where the .json is (to have only /filename.json as the import path)
2. `mongosh "mongodb+srv://<username>.ck3ra.mongodb.net/<database>" --username <username>`

step 2 is successful and asks for a `<password>`, which I input.
my cd becomes:

```
<Atlas identifier> [primary] <database> >
```

so I know I'm logged into my database.

3. execute command:

`mongoimport --host <collection Primary address> --db <database> --type json --file /<filename>.json -jsonArray --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username <username> --password <password>`

after doing step 3, the error is:

> Uncaught: SyntaxError: Missing semicolon. (1:14)

This error happens regardless of full path or relative path to the json, so it's not about some syntax in the command itself, I think, but I can't figure out what the error is.

Thanks

Comment: `mongoimport` is to be run from OS command prompt. Its also possible, to import from Compass.

Comment: @prasad_ it doesn't matter where I run it from, still the same error... what is Compass? can you elaborate with some details? how is it related to MongoDB atlas and json files?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, MongoDB Compass did the trick after some work.